# WindowsCE device with single NIC - Two IP address ranges

Tags: networking, router, ip, network-adapter, windows-ce

I have a question about a windows CE device which has a single NIC (and no possibility to extend the device with a second NIC). This device is configured to use a fixed address.

CE Device:
IP:  `192.168.1.20`
SNM: `255.255.255.0`

Now, the CE device communicates via a switch to a few other devices which are within the same range and network (for example `192.168.1.19`).

The CE device generates a logfile to a network location. This location is no located within the 192.168.1.xx range. But i want the logfile to be written to another network (which is in a complete other range (for example `192.168.2.xxx`).

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your device would be able to reach 192.168.2.X if it had a default gateway set to a router that could forward to that subnet.

If you already have a router accessible via this switch, simply specify it's IP as the default gateway on your CE device, or enable DHCP if you have a DHCP server running.